# XPath works differently with HtmlPage and XHtmlPage

Tags: java, htmlunit

Depending on the value of the *Content-Type* header `webClient.getPage(url)` returns an instance of `HtmlPage` or `XHtmlPage`. The problem is XPath does not work the same way in both objects. See the example below:

```
    String html = "<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>"
        + "<head title='test page'></head>"
        + "<body><h1>Test Page</h1></body></html>";

    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    MockWebConnection wcon = new MockWebConnection();
    client.setWebConnection(wcon);

    wcon.setDefaultResponse(html, 200, "OK", "text/html");
    HtmlPage hPage = client.getPage("http://localhost");
    Assert.assertNotNull(hPage.getFirstByXPath("//:h1")); // fails
    Assert.assertNotNull(hPage.getFirstByXPath("//h1")); // Ok

    wcon.setDefaultResponse(html, 200, "OK", "text/xml");
    HtmlPage xPage = client.getPage("http://localhost"); // instanceof XHtmlPage
    Assert.assertNotNull(xPage.getFirstByXPath("//:h1")); // Ok
    Assert.assertNotNull(xPage.getFirstByXPath("//h1")); // fails
```

Is this behaviour expected? Is there a way to use the same XPath expression in both `HtmlPage` and `XHtmlPage`?